Comparing outcomes from 2 diagnostic criteria (McNemar Exact Test?)
First time poster here.
I am stuck trying to figure out the correct statistical test for my research question.
I am comparing two possible outcomes using the results from the same dataset. These criteria are designated post-analysis on the same results from the same samples.
Essentially, I ran a triplicate assay and want to see if there is a difference in outcomes when considering at least one positive well a positive diagnosis or considering at least 2 positive wells a positive diagnosis (i.e. assessing false negatives between methods).
Since they are the same samples, I made a contigency table and tried a McNemar test, but with the 0 in the discordant cell I wasn't sure if it works (it is impossible for this cell to have a non-zero value due to the criteria).
If I try a McNemar exact test, the pvalue is very very small...and I am not even sure if it's right or if this test is correct for my circumstances.




Positive (>2 Wells)
Negative (>2 Wells)




Positive(>1 Well)
45
30


Negative(>1 Well)
0
351



mcnemar_test <- mcnemar.test(contingency_table1)
Any advice on which test to use would help. Thanks a million.

It seems like literature consensus that if the unequal-responses n is above 25, asymptoptic McNemar is viable. In your example, that n is 30+0, so I believe you may still use asymptotic McNemar. If it is below 25 or 26, the exact version based on Binomial distribution, with or without Mid-p correction, is surely preferable.

McNemar's test a paired-samples test for dichotomous data with the same categories. That is, you have 2 columns (variables), both with categories "true" and "false" (or such). It tests only for equality of counts in the two cells: true-false and false-true.

the McNemar test is useful in your scenario to compare two diagnostic criteria. But, as you mentioned, a cell with zero counts in the contingency table can cause a problem for the traditional McNemar test, if these cells have a zero count, the standard McNemar test may not be useful.
Instead of this, you can use the McNemar exact test. it is more suitable for small sample sizes and when there are zero counts, it uses a binomial approach rather than a chi-square approach while calculating the p-value.
Here is more detail,
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exact2x2/vignettes/exactMcNemar.pdf

Hi, thanks for the quick feedback.
Yes, I was looking at the McNemar exact test.
I tried the {exact2x2} package in R on the contingency table and am getting the following:
Exact McNemar test (with central confidence intervals)
data:  contingency_table
b = 30, c = 0, p-value = 1.863e-09
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
7.642795      Inf
sample estimates:
odds ratio
Inf

Based on my criteria, there can never be a non-zero value in one of the discordant cells because if there are negative results when at least one well is positive, then by definition it will be negative when at least 2 wells are positive.
I am concerned this is an issue, but it is the reality of what I am trying to test!

Do you know the "ground truth"? If you do, I would not use a McNemar test. I would compute sensitivity/specificity for both, with CI's, and plot those on a ROC graph, to see if the gain in specificity of the 2-wells test is "worth" the loss in sensitivity. It should be obvious that the 2-wells test will have lower sensitivity and higher specificity (and indeed, 2-wells "fails" to catch 30 subjects which were caught by the 1-well test). But McNemar does not tell you if this was a "good" change; it just says the 2 tests are not "identical".  Which feels rather obvious to me?

@jginestet Thanks for the response. I see what you are saying. I am starting to think that maybe I don't need a statistical test at all.   The percentages alone show that we are missing positives if we exclude one well (and as you said, it is rather obvious)...Maybe just talking about it descriptively is enough.
I don't have any ground truth data. I am setting the criteria myself on two independent Runs of samples in triplicate.
Maybe there is a way to compare the false positives otained from each Run as opposed to comparing the criteria themselves...if that makes sense.

For example, in the first run, I can say 30/45 (66.7%) are missing if we use a min. two well criteria (sample size n=396).
In the second run, it was 6/23 (26.1%, n=110).
Maybe comparing the rate of false positives by each run is more effective.
However I'm not sure how.

If you do not have a ground truth, you can not say if what you missed were FP's (good ridance) or TP's (disaster). Can you "create" samples of known outcome? Samples you know, from other clinical evidence are positives/negatives? Samples which you "spiked" with antigens (or whatever you are trying to detect)? Reference samples from other labs? Etc.  Yes, it begs the question of how good you can be at "simulating" samples... Depending on the specifics, it can sometimes be possible/credible.

@jginestet  I meant to say false negatives, not false positives in my above comment. Vocabulary-wise I am saying that using one method misclassifies infected individuals as uninfected...therefore we are underestimating disease prevalence.
I am making a point because in the literature some researchers are not counting 1 well as a positive even when it detects the pathogen. So I want to show with my samples, hypothetically...what we could be missing if we change the diagnostic criteria.
